# How to show activity only once until setup is complete in android studio

Tags: android-studio, mobile, mobile-development

I am creating an app where the user can decide if he/she wants to setup or upgrade his/her account so that he/she can sell products. In that app there is a 4 bottom navigation menu fragments (`Home`, `Purchases`, `Sell`, `Account`). When the user clicks the `Sell menu` it shows if the user wants to sell or not and there is a `Get Started button`. So if the user want to sell a product, the user will click the `get started` button and the user will setup his/her account. So after the user finishes the account setup I want to change the layout in `Sell menu` where the user can now sell items. Now when the user clicks the `Sell menu` instead of seeing the `get started button`, the user will now see the options to sell items. I want to implement this and I do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

You need create authentication program for check user already log in or not. There plenty tutorial for make this program depend your requirement so you need google it yourself.